# What is the scalaz-stream equivalent to Play Framework's Enumerator.fromCallback

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

Play Framework's iteratee library defines a method `Enumerator.fromCallback` which allows elements to be generated based on the results of a Future:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Enumerators

```
def fromCallback[E](
  retriever: () => Future[Option[E]],
  onComplete: () => Unit = () => (),
  onError: (String, Input[E]) => Unit = (_: String, _: Input[E]) => ()
): Enumerator[E]
```

You can see a nice example of it being used to deliver paginated results from a Web service here:

http://engineering.klout.com/2013/01/iteratees-in-big-data-at-klout/

```
def pagingEnumerator(url:String):Enumerator[JsValue]={
  var maybeNextUrl = Some(url) //Next url to fetch
  Enumerator.fromCallback[JsValue] ( retriever = {
    val maybeResponsePromise =
      maybeNextUrl map { nextUrl=>  
        WS.url(nextUrl).get.map { reponse =>
          val json = response.json
          maybeNextUrl = (json \ "next_url").asOpt[String]
          val code = response.status //Potential error handling here
          json
        }   
      }

    /* maybeResponsePromise will be an Option[Promise[JsValue]].
     * Need to 'flip' it, to make it a Promise[Option[JsValue]] to
     * conform to the fromCallback constraints */
    maybeResponsePromise match {
      case Some(responsePromise) => responsePromise map Some.apply
      case None => PlayPromise pure None
    }
  })
}
```

What is the equivalent scalaz-stream code for doing the same?  I'm pretty sure it can be done using `Process.emit` or `Process.await` or maybe `Process.eval`, but I'd love to see a worked-out example.  This might also require lifting the scala Future into a scalaz Task, for which there's an answer here:

[Convert scala 2.10 future to scalaz.concurrent.Future // Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895635/convert-scala-2-10-future-to-scalaz-concurrent-future-task)

If it makes things simpler, we can ignore the scala Future vs scalaz Task bit and assume we have a Task.

Comment: There is an example in the repo that shows how to create a Process from a callback: [CreatingStreams.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/test/scala/scalaz/stream/examples/CreatingStreams.scala#L76)

Answer (score 2):

To get scalaz.concurrent.Task from scala.concurrent.Future you can use Task.async, when you've got task in your hand you can do it this way:

```
  import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
  import scalaz.concurrent.Task
  import scalaz.stream.Process.End
  import scalaz.stream._

  val cnt = new AtomicInteger(0)

  val task: Task[String] = Task {
    if (cnt.incrementAndGet() <= 10) s"Task ${cnt.get}" else throw End
  }

  Process.repeatEval(task).runLog.run.foreach(println)
```

Comment: I added Task.async step, you can take a look at full example here: https://gist.github.com/ezhulenev/10553038